# How can i clear variable?

Tags: javascript

In my code `bq` is not reset. when I erased my first input and put another value, it will still display the first value . how can i clear the value of the variable `bq`.

```
var t="";
var bq="";
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var val =$(this).val();

    if(val=='') {
        bq="";
    } else {
        for(val;val>0;val--) {
            bq="";
            bq=(t+='[ '+[val]+'f ]');
        }
    }
    $('p').text(bq);
}).keyup();
```

Comment: What you trying to achieve here ? Can you post your HTML code as well ?

Comment: could you create a JSFIDDLE for that?  i'm trying to replicate it but i'm not sure with the result. https://jsfiddle.net/zcwmm6g5/

Comment: What are you entering into the input? It looks like *val* should be a number.

Comment: First i don't know why you need a for loop... You can easily done using this...
http://jsfiddle.net/8q2fm2mf/

Comment: I input a number. when i input 2 it wil display [2f][1f] and input again 2 it will display [2f][1f][2f][1f] ..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the variable `bq` 'coz it's always resets its value, 
you just forgot to reset the variable `t` that's why it still displays the previous value

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var val =$(this).val();
    t=""; // <-- you can reset it here
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zcwmm6g5/4/)**